# How to implement Server sent events in Actix?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, actix-web

I am trying to implement server-sent events in Rust using Actix Web. I'm just trying to stream OpenAI responses to the client. I have figured out how to handle the stream from OpenAI but I'm not sure how to send this to the user.

My code:

```
use actix_web::{get, post, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use actix_web_lab::sse;
use async_stream;
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use futures_util;
use reqwest;
use reqwest::Client;
use reqwest_eventsource::{Event, EventSource};
use serde_json;
use std::{convert::Infallible, f32::consts::E, time::Duration};
use tokio::time::sleep;

#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
 let response = reqwest::Client::new()
        .post(open_ai_completion_url)
        .header("api-key", open_ai_key)
        .json(&serde_json::json!({
            "messages": [
                {"role": "system", "content": "History of USA?"},
            ],
            "max_tokens": 10,
            "temperature": 0,
            "stream": true,
        }));

    let mut es = EventSource::new(response).expect("Failed to create EventSource");
    while let Some(event) = es.next().await {
        match event {
            Ok(Event::Open) => println!("Connection Open!"),
            Ok(Event::Message(message)) => {
                println!("Message: {:#?}", message); // not sure how to send this messages to user
            }
            Err(err) => {
                println!("Error: {}", err);
                es.close();
            }
        }
    }

    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a stream with the right response:

```rust
async fn sse() -> impl Responder {
    let es = EventSource::new(response).expect("Failed to create EventSource");

    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .insert_header((http::header::CONTENT_TYPE, "text/event-stream"))
        .insert_header(ContentEncoding::Identity)
        .streaming(es)
}
```

This should pipe the event stream. You may use `StreamExt::map` to change the event type. You could also use channels if you need more customization.

Comment: Can I ask why the original post uses the term reqwest .. its like I want to wequest a wariable pwease ?

Comment: @easleyfixed I think its a play on `request`. I guess that name was already taken.

Comment: Ahh yes yeah it is probably a protected term, I guess thats one way to do it, didn't know if it was part of the language or a personal choice.

Comment: @easleyfixed [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) is a popular HTTP library

Comment: There we go, ty!